pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Error de sintaxis o infracción de acceso (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
estoy empezando a programar, es lo primero que hago en python pero tengo un detalle que no he podido encontrar, tengo que actualizar una vista en Miscrosoft SQL con un input del usuario para actualizar una fecha pero al ejecutar el codigo me manda como texto la variable
import pyodbc
connection=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-G39D051\COMPAC;DATABASE=PruebasLuis;UID=sa;PWD=123456;')
print("Conexion Exitosa")
print ("Fecha YYYY-MM-DD:")
Fecha  = input()
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("ALTER VIEW CS_orgProductKardex AS SELECT LTRIM(dbo.FORMAT(DateTransaction, N'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS DateTransaction, DepotID, ProductID, DocumentID, DocumentItemID, Quantity, QuantityToBeDelivered, AmountPrice, Cancelled, ProductImportID, DepotValue,  DepotValueAverage, QuantityImport FROM dbo.orgProductKardex WHERE (LTRIM(dbo.FORMAT(DateTransaction, N'YYYY-MM-DD')) <= '{Fecha}')")
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
